# How do I conditionally format all rows in a table, to display a different colour based on a cells value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have developed a table (as seen below) which is designed to show a persons duties based on priority.

If a person clicks the toggle on/off button, this will toggle colours on the rows of the table, red, yellow and green to make it visually easier to understand the priority level.

[Picture showing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi5pt.png)

The idea is that I want each row in the table to display 3 different colours, RED, YELLOW AND GREEN, depending on the priority that is showing up.  When I have applied conditional formatting to the entire table however, it seems to only apply the formula to the very top row, where as I want to apply it to all rows.

The formula's are set up as seen below:
=AND($N20="Overdue",$N17=TRUE)

Where N20 is the row where the spreadsheet declares the priority, and N17 is where the checkbox provides its true / false value.

[Example of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzKDn.png)

[Overview of rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aULfZ.png)

The formula once again works but only applies it to the top row.  I have tried using the format painter also, but this too does not work.

I am assuming I have put something wrong in the formula but can not see what.

Any help is appreciated, a fresh pair of eyes sometimes helps.

Comment: Since TRUE is not the part of the data range you are trying to apply conditional formatting so that your formula is not working. What you have to do in `P20` write this formula `=if(And(N20="Overdue",N17=TRUE),"True", "False")` & fill down, then select entire rows including `Col P`, and apply this for Condition Formatting, `=And($N20="Overdue",$P20="True")` & select color and others, will work properly & highlight all rows have OVERDUE & TRUE. PLz confirm whether it's works or not, for me it's working.

Comment: Spot on, this was exactly what I was looking for, the only thing I had to change from your P20 code was =if(And(N20="Overdue",N$17=TRUE),"True", "False"), since the field N17 is a constant and I didnt want it to change as i copied across other fields.

All I now need to do is create a nested If statement which has 3 outcomes rather than just the one.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: The formula I've suggested in creating **HELPER Column** only & the Value in `N17` will be un-touched.  Excel will put TRUE & FALSE in the Column to help you  to Format the Range.

Comment: Yeah this is all sorted now, thanks so much for your help.

I ended up modifying your formula to feature the other conditions, so it would trigger the other colours:

=IF(AND(OR(N21="Low Priority",N21="Medium Priority",N21="High Priority",N21="Overdue"),N$17=TRUE),"True", "False")

Thank you once again for all your help, once again another set of eyes really does help.

Since you answered it, I think its only fair you disclose the answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: If my solution works and you feel I can post the Solution here also, will help you and others too !

Comment: Yeah post the solution.

Comment: Now I've posted the Solution,, I happy to help you, keep asking.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating the Solution it really encourage me & others too, have nice time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since TRUE is not the part of data range you are trying to format conditionally so that you need to create one Helper Column.*

[image]

1. Write this formula in **F63** & fill it down.

   `=IF(AND(E63="Overdue",G63=TRUE),"True","False")`
2. Select `A63:F66` & Create `New Rule` for conditional formatting, use
   this formula for the Rule:

`=AND($E63="Overdue",$F$63="True")`

- Finish with applying an appropriate color.

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references in formula as needed.
- You can modify above shown formula according to your use as you have
  shown in the comments above, Will help you to solve the issue.